# Как сделать динамическую проверку формы?

Tags: ajax, php, html

Есть форма регистрации на сайте:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="reg">
 <input type="text" size="20" maxlength="35" name="name" id="name" value="">
<form>
```

В отдельном файле функция проверки длины (не менее 2 и не более 20 символов) и проверки на совпадение в БД.

Как сделать, чтобы после того как с поля NAME уйдет фокус (не знаю, как правильно выразиться) данные из формы передавались в скрипт, проверялись, и возвращался некий html код, или хотя бы текст (если все правильно один текст, если нет - другой)

Умные люди говорят, что это делается через ajax. Я как бы не против, но не знаю как написать скрипт.
Можете привести пример как такое делать?

Comment: Огромное спасибо за советы! 
Нашел пару скриптов, подправил, теперь работает =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если есть готовый скрипт валидации, то, я так понял, вам только событие нужно. OnBlur - противоположное OnFocus.

```
<input type="text" size="20" maxlength="35" name="name" id="name" value="" onblur="return validate();" />
```

А функция validate() соотв-но проверяет содержимое. можно сделать validate(inputID, value) и писать

```
onblur="return validate(this.id, this.value);"
```

Comment: а в функции validate нужно произвести ajax запрос

Comment: Я с аяксом просто не работаю (своя библиотека), поэтому ничего писать про него не стал. Но да, проверка на длину, потом аякс, наверно.

Answer (score 1):

а еще у тега input есть атрибут pattern, который позволяет задавать шаблон ввода для элемента

Answer (score 0):

Вбейте в гугле "jquery form validation". Пара ссылок:

- [jquery form validation (eng.)](http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/jquery/form_validation/)
- [form validation (рус.)](http://www.linkexchanger.su/2008/45.html)